# Prolog book database (how to get results grouped by author?)

Tags: prolog

I have a the following database of facts like:

`...
book(title1, author1),
book(title2, author2),
book(title3, author3),
book(title4, author1),
book(title5, author2),
...`

I need to write a prolog query or rule to get titles grouped by the author (author1, author2...). I can't change order of facts in database.

For now I have only query looking like this:
book(T1, A), book(T2, A), T1 \= T2.
but it returns same thing few times

thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to take a look at findall\3.

Comment: You need to collect a unique list of authors first, so you could do `author_title(Author, Title) :- setof(A, T^book(T, A), Authors), member(Author, Authors), book(Title, Author).`

Comment: thanks, it works great